# Keyboard shortcut to transpose characters around cursor

Tags: shortcut-keys, text

In Emacs (and MacOS) typing control+t will transpose the characters around the cursor in any input field. For example if I type

`helol<c-t>`

`hello`

results. Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu? I'm imagining a solution using something like [sxhkd](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) that involves copying the previous 2 characters, deleting them, and pasting a transposed version, but I imagine this would look distracting and take a little while to execute.

I already have Emacs keys enabled system wide but apparently this is not one of the shortcuts it offers.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04.06, `bash` shell, gnome-termnal, terminal set to `emacs`, `^T` works for me. If I type `abcd^T` I see `abdc`

Comment: @waltinator it's true that some apps support `^T`, but ideally I'd be able to use it across all apps, including my browser.

Comment: A universal solution working both in terminal and in any app probably will not be available in linux. For terminal, indeed you can switch to emacs editing mode. For graphical applications, xdotool will work - it is not as distracting or slow as you fear, but it has its caveats. In addition, one would also need a way to disable the hotkey used to launch the xdotool script  when a terminal is active.